# Is there a mitzva to redeem a wealthy captive?

Tags: psych-mentalhealth, shoteh-mental-incompetent, pidyon-shvuyim-prisoners

Suppose a wealthy man is taken captive, and the ransom set is an amount that he certainly can cover, but for whatever reason (perhaps mental illness) he chooses not to.

Is there still a mitzva to pay his ransom so he can be set free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch [YD 252:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.252?lang=bi) says that you take his money and redeem him against his will:

> מי שנשבה ויש לו נכסים ואינו רוצה לפדות עצמו פודים אותו בעל כרחו:

> If a captive has property but does not wish to ransom himself, his ransom is paid against his will.

Comment: It doesn't say you take the money from him.

Comment: See the Biur hagra that connects to the Gemara about using his own money

Comment: @Chatzkel can you link to it?

Comment: @lgshost https://www.sefaria.org/Beur_HaGra_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.252.16?lang=bi

Answer (score 0):

From [sosrabbi.com](https://sosrabbi.com), yes because in fact he could be considered as 'poor' due to his illness. But on the other hand, one of the main purposes of the commandment to redeem captives (pidyon shvuyim) is to let the captive continue with his religious obligation. If the man's illness is such that he couldnt do, the mitzvah could be less applicable.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Gad and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @mbloch is this answer not just AI generated drivel?

Comment: I asked the ia and rephrased it. It still make sense to me.

Comment: @Gad please don't do this - if people wanted an IA answer, they would ask any of the engines